# How to create an occupancy grid map in python similar to Matlab occupancy grid

Tags: python, grid, robotics

I am aiming to create an occupancy grid as following in Matlab:

(https://au.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ug/occupancy-grids.html)

```
map = binaryOccupancyMap(10,10,5);
setOccupancy(map,[5 5], 1);
```

I have googled and got overwhelmed with Python's robotics algorithms. 
Could anyone please help to instruct a simple way to do in python?